# Having Trouble Fixing Issues with Selenium 4.11.2 selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version114

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I created a script last month, and now I can't run it. I've already checked other Stack Overflow posts about this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114. Current browser version is 116.0.5845.110`. However, the suggested solutions haven't worked for me.

I've already upgraded my Selenium to version 4.11.2 and removed the /.cache/selenium/chrome directory, but it still doesn't work.

Sometimes, when I run the script in the terminal, a message appears mentioning that Selenium can't use version 116. It then attempts to use version 115, but encounters the same issue. Subsequently, it tries version 144. After this, the script starts running, but eventually crashes due to incompatibility between the ChromeDriver version and the browser version.

This is part of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

class WebScrapping:
   def __init__(self,url,graphic_mode):
       self.scraped_list = []
       self.scraped_names = []
       self.service = Service()
       self.options = Options()
       prefs = {}
       prefs["intl.accept_languages"] = "en_us"
       self.options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    

       if graphic_mode.lower() == "enable" or graphic_mode.lower() == "on":
           self.url = f"{url}"
           self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
           self.driver.get(self.url)
           self.driver.execute_script(f"document.title = '{url}';")
       elif graphic_mode.lower() == "disable" or graphic_mode.lower() == "off":
           self.options.add_argument("--headless=new")
           self.url = f"{url}"
           self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=self.service,options=self.options)
           self.driver.get(self.url)
           self.driver.execute_script(f"document.title = '{url}';")
       else:
           print("Please use on or off, to enable or disable the graphic mode")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the same problem by downloading the chromedriver which is compatible with Chrome for testing 116, you can download it from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable depending on your operating system (Linux, Windows, etc).

Once you've done this, you need to set the executable path, so I think that you should modify the following line:

`self.service = Service(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver.exe")` if you downloaded the chromedriver for Windows, or

`self.service = Service(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver")` for Linux (or whatever the name it has).

This should solve the problem, otherwise please share the log error.